# Thrust : how could i fill an array by range with index and range

Tags: c++, thrust

I try to fill an array by range using index and values

```
   thrust::device_vector<int> vec(12) 
    vec[1] = 2;
    vec[6] = 3;
    vec[10] = 1;
```

the result should be

```
vec { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

instead i have

```
vec { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

does some could tell where i'm wrong ?
Thanks

Here my code :

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
struct FillRange
{
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& res, const T& dat)
    {
        return dat >= T(0)  ? dat : 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<int> vec(12);
    vec[1] = 2;
    vec[6] = 3;
    vec[10] = 2;

    thrust::inclusive_scan(
            vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(),
            vec.rbegin(),
            FillRange<int>());

    thrust::copy(
            vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the `res` variable that your function body never uses? You also wrote your operator overload to take parameters, but don't provide any. This could just be my lack of familiarity with the library you're using.

Comment: @sweenish `FillRange<int>()` is just the constructor. The algorithm will call that functor with arguments. But yes not using the `res` parameter in a scan algorithm seems to make no sense (could just use a transform).

Comment: No idea how the given code would produce the expected result. I would be interested in the thought process behind it to find out where the problem lies.

Comment: res is here because when i start FillRange  was written like this : ``` __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& res, const T& dat)
    {
        return dat == T(0)  ? res : dat;
    } ```  which fill the gap in the array with the value :  2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2

Comment: You will have to use `res`, otherwise the result for each element only depends on the element itself and not on earlier (in your code later, b/c you use reverse iterators, no idea why you are using those here) elements. My idea would be to first try to go to `vec { 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}` via the binary operator and then use a transform iterator for the output to go to your expected result.

Comment: thanks i made the change like this ```    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& res, const T& dat)
    {
        return ((res-1)>0)?res-1 :dat;
    }`` and so i get this result  vec{ 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 1 2 } why things go from right to left  and not left to right. I'm sorry i don't understand why.

Comment: That is because you use reverse iterators. Try `begin` and `end` instead of `rbegin` and `rend`.

Comment: Thank for all thinks work fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code for the expected result.

The array give index and the number of flag to be set:
so for

```
   thrust::device_vector<int> vec(12) 
    vec[1] = 2;
    vec[6] = 3;
    vec[10] = 1;
```

the result will be

```
vec { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}
```

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <iterator>


struct clean_
{
    __host__ __device__ 
    int operator()(const int &p1) const
    {
        return (p1>0)?1:p1;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct FillRange
{
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& res, const T& dat)
    {
        return ((res-1)>0)? res-1 : dat ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<int> vec(12);
    vec[1] = 2;
    vec[6]  = 3;
    vec[11] = 2;

    thrust::inclusive_scan(
            vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            vec.begin(),
            FillRange<int>());

    thrust::transform(
            vec.begin(), 
              vec.end(),
            vec.begin(),
            clean_());

    thrust::copy(
            vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hope everything is clearer now.